# How to close searchbar after returning a new screen ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, search, navigation

```
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
....

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return MyProfile();
  }
.....
}
```

this is the code for search delegate

i tried Close() Method but it close the Profile Screen also
when i use navigate method same as image [image: Search bar still exist above appbar]

where should i use close method or am doing it in a wrong way ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Add this at your `on search complete`

```
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
```

Comment: should i try it in buildresult method ?

Comment: @ialyzaafan put it anywhere where you need it to close the search bar so if you want to close it after your buildresult sure.